# Painter error in paintCell() function when subclassing QCalendarWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcalendarwidget

I want to create calendar, that will mark several dates  entered by user.
So I have subclassed QCalendarWidget and reimplemented painCell function.
Here is my simplified code:

```
MyCalendar::MyCalendar(QWidget *parent)
    : QCalendarWidget(parent)
{   
    painter = new QPainter(this);   
}
void MyCalendar::setHolidays(QDate date)
{
    paintCell(painter, rect(),date);        
}

void MyCalendar::paintCell(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, const QDate & date) const
{
    painter->setBrush(Qt::red);
    QCalendarWidget::paintCell(painter, rect, date);
}
```

I can't do it though, because when creating QPainter object i am getting this message:
"QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1"

When I am not setting painter parent, I get this error when trying to set brush:
"QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active"
I think, I am creating QPainter object in a wrong place.
Anyone knows, how to resolve this?

I was using Qt wiki snippet:
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_custom_calender_widget

Comment: `painter.setBrush(Qt::red);` or `painter->setBrush(Qt::red);`?

Comment: Right, painter->setBrush(Qt::red). But this is not the problem, I made this mistake when editing my code here, on stack page

Comment: I believe, calling `paintCell()` in `setHolidays()` might be the wrong way. Instead, IMHO `setHolydays()` should call `updateCells()` (or `updateCell()` for a specific date). The `paintCell()` is a virtual method which is called out of the `paint()` method (inherited from `QWidget`). It should check for a special day to modify appearance. It probably gets a `QPainter` instance as argument which is managed inside `QCalendarWidget` - no need to create your own. I just see the answer of eyllanesc. It seems he had the same idea...

Comment: As you mentioned the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on the Qt Wiki, there is also a bigger [Calendar Widget Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calendarwidget-example.html) in Qt doc. which I find worth to be mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not draw directly since the paintCell method is called internally, it is appropriate to save the dates in a list, and if the date used by paintCell is contained in that list, draw it in a personalized way:

```
#ifndef MYCALENDAR_H
#define MYCALENDAR_H

#include <QCalendarWidget>
#include <QPainter>
class MyCalendar : public QCalendarWidget
{
public:
    MyCalendar(QWidget *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QCalendarWidget{parent}{

    }
    void addHoliday(const QDate &date){
        mDates<<date;
        updateCell(date);
    }
    void paintCell(QPainter * painter, const QRect & rect, const QDate & date) const{
        if(mDates.contains(date)){
            painter->save();
            painter->setBrush(Qt::red);
            painter->drawRect(rect);
            painter->drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter|Qt::TextSingleLine, QString::number(date.day()));
            painter->restore();
        }
        else
            QCalendarWidget::paintCell(painter, rect, date);

    }
private:
    QList<QDate> mDates;
};

#endif // MYCALENDAR_H
```

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the mechanism. Is there any way, that these red rectangle will change colour when clicked, like other rects in calendar?
Maybe implement on click slot, that will check if these date belongs to m_Dates, and if it does change its colour to blue, like every cell in calendar

Comment: Of course, QCalendarWidget has the clicked signal that the QDate gives you, then at that moment it saves it in a list and works in the same way as in the example.